# Positioning Absolute Elements Below Each Other

Tags: css, css-position, css-transitions, fixed

I am attempting to create a CSS3 hover menu that transitions out and shows sub menus below it. The problem I am having is that I can't position the submenus below each other. Currently, I have this effect - http://jsfiddle.net/7pz3g/1/

Here is the HTML markup -

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="iconContainer">
        <li>
            <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
            <ul id="wrapperFirst" class="extMenu">
                <li><h3>Testing</h3></li>
                <li>SubMenu
                    <ul id="wrapperSecond" class="subMenu">
                        <li><h3>ORGANIZATIONS</h3></li>
                        <li><a href="http://reddit.com/‎">Reddit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS MarkUp -

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #333333;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 60px;
    display: table;
}

#navbar .iconContainer li {
    color: white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
}

#navbar .iconContainer li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);    
}

#navbar i {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    width: 60px;
    opacity: .5;
}

#navbar .iconContainer {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 510;
}

#navbar li:hover i {
    background-color: #222222;
    opacity: 1;
}

#navbar li:hover #wrapperFirst.extMenu {
    left: 60px;
}

#wrapperFirst.extMenu {
    background-color: #222;
    height: 100%;
    left: -1000px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#wrapperFirst.extMenu .raq {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    color: #75A4C7;
}

#wrapperFirst.extMenu li:hover #wrapperSecond.subMenu {
    left: 311px;
}

#wrapperFirst.extMenu li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapperFirst.extMenu li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 100%;
    left: -1000px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu .subtitle {
    font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular';
    font-size: .6em;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #75A4C7;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu li {
    opacity: 1;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu {
    width: 600px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu .subtitle {
    font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular';
    font-size: .6em;
}

#wrapperSecond.subMenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #75A4C7;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

I would like to have each submenu transition below their root menus, but yet still stay on top of the other elements on the page. Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ypzcG/

```
#wrapperSecond.subMenu li {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```